# How to make four bar plots with different heights and having a certain percentage of common color

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have 100 days of raw data. Four methods have identified a different number of useful days data.

```
raw_days = 100
# Useful days identified by different methods
Met1 = 92 
Met2 = 93 
Met3 = 96 
Met4 = 91
commondays = 88 # Number of common useful days in four methods
```

I want to represent the above information in bar plots. I don't know if this is possible. At the end, What I want to see is a bar plot something like shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer partially and leave the part about annotating the bars up to you. You can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart) for annotations

```
raw_days = 100
# Useful days identified by different methods
Met1 = 92 
Met2 = 93 
Met3 = 96 
Met4 = 91
commondays = 88 

plt.bar(range(4), [Met1, Met2, Met3, Met4], color='r', ec='k')
plt.bar(range(4), [commondays]*4, color='w', hatch='/', ec='k', label='common useful \ndays in four methods')
plt.xticks(range(4), ['Met%i'%i for i in range(1, 5)])
plt.yticks([])
plt.legend(loc=(1.05, 0.5))
plt.ylabel('Useful days')
```

[image]

Comment: How to fill a color or more lines or dots in common useful days in above bar plot?

Comment: Thanks for udpating. I wanted a color, instead slope lines, in the common useful days. Red color in four plots misrepresents information.

Comment: @Msquare Try using `color='red',` in the second line and use `color='none',` in the first. See if this is what you want

Comment: Thanks for update. How to show values(92%, 88%, 93%,88%,.. ) in each bar like I showed in my question?

Comment: @Msquare : Check the link I added in my answer. Google "annotating bar chart with values matplotlib"

Comment: Thanks for update. I checked it. It is useful. But how to get two values in one bar chart? like my first bar showing 92% at top and 88% below?

Comment: @Msquare : Add these two lines `plt.text(-0.8, 88, '88%')` and `plt.xlim(-1, 4)`

Comment: I tried this code `plt.text(-0.8,useful_common,'.f%'%(useful_common))`  but I got following error: `ValueError: incomplete format`

Comment: @Msquare : Try using `'%d'%(useful_common))'`

Comment: I got it. It was my mistake. Many thanks for solving it.